# Java 8 .jar file won't run from desktop using Netbeans 8.0.2 to compile WITH EXTERNAL LIBRARY; runs fine if library is included in source

Tags: java-8, netbeans-8

***EDIT***

The **jar file now runs from the desktop** after clean and build and copying it there ***BUT*** to make it happen I had to **delete the external library** containing `Utilities.jar` and include the source as another java class.

**This isn't acceptable** but maybe it tells what to do to make the problem below go away.

When compiling with external library containing `Utilities.jar`, I find a `lib` folder inside the `dist` folder, and inside it is `Utilities.jar`.

The `Readme.txt` file in the `dist` folder says:

```
        ======================== BUILD OUTPUT DESCRIPTION =====

        When you build an Java application project that has a main class, the IDE
     automatically copies all of the JAR files on the projects classpath to your
     projects dist/lib folder. The IDE also adds each of the JAR files to the 
    Class-Path element in the application JAR files manifest file (MANIFEST.MF).

        To run the project from the command line, go to the dist folder and 
    type the following:

        java -jar "MrCopy.jar" 

        To distribute this project, zip up the dist folder (including the 
    lib folder) and distribute the ZIP file.

        Notes:

        * If a library on the projects classpath also has a Class-Path element 
        specified in the manifest, the content 
        of the Class-Path element has to be on the projects runtime path.
```

Here's what's in `manifest.mf`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
```

Should I add anything to it?

If I follow the advice in the `readme` and "zip up the .jar and `lib` folder" and put the `.zip` folder on the desktop and unzip it and run the .jar file, the program runs normally, as it should.

And if I run from command line from the `dist` folder via `javac -jar mrcopy.jar`, it of course runs right.

But I've never had to go through all this just to get an executable .jar file.

I'm so confused.................

**Is it just this simple:
If I have external libraries, I'm going to have to zip them up, distribute the zip, unzip the zip and run the .jar file from wherever it got unzipped to?**

**End of edit**

For years, after modifying and compiling `MrCopy.jar`, I could copy the .jar file (that is found in the `...\NetBeansProjects\MrCopy\dist` folder) to my desktop and run it. Here's what SHOULD happen:

[image]

That dialog pops up and clicking YES leads to copying and the screen below at end:

[image]

But now that I'm compiling (as of today) using `JAVA 8` in Project Properties `Source\Binary format`, I don't get the first dialog and nothing happens.

Here's what Project Properties Packaging looks like:

[image]

What can I do to make .jar file run from desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understanding right, you have a project with dependencies from other libs?

If so, you could do two things to distribute your app:

1 - create a fat Jar you can see it [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-build-fat-jar-using)

2 - zip the content of the project/dist folder just like you said

Comment: Thanks, @liponcio. I'd never heard of "fat jar". Where did you learn about this procedure?

Comment: This has been problematic lately. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084032/errors-in-ant-file-in-netbeans-8-0-2-come-and-go-but-no-java-source-errors)?