# Errors in Ant file in Netbeans 8.0.2 come and go but no .java source errors

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I followed [this procedure](https://dzone.com/articles/how-build-fat-jar-using) to make a "fat" .jar file--one that contains external libraries inside executable .jar file.

But as often as not, and for no specific reason I can put my finger on, I get errors on both lines with ******* on them in `\nbproject\build-impl.xml`:

```
    <target depends="init,-init-macrodef-copylibs,compile,-pre-pre-jar,-pre-jar,-do-jar-create-manifest,-do-jar-copy-manifest,-do-jar-set-mainclass,-do-jar-set-profile,-do-jar-set-splashscreen" if="do.mkdist" name="-do-jar-copylibs">


********<j2seproject3:copylibs manifest="${tmp.manifest.file}"/>


        <echo level="info">To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:</echo>
        <property location="${dist.jar}" name="dist.jar.resolved"/>
        <echo level="info">java -jar "${dist.jar.resolved}"</echo>
    </target>



***************<copylibs compress="${jar.compress}" excludeFromCopy="${copylibs.excludes}" index="${jar.index}" indexMetaInf="${jar.index.metainf}" jarfile="${dist.jar}" manifest="@{manifest}" rebase="${copylibs.rebase}" runtimeclasspath="${run.classpath.without.build.classes.dir}">


                    <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}" excludes="${dist.archive.excludes}"/>
                    <manifest>
                        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}"/>
                        <customize/>
                    </manifest>
                </copylibs>
```

The errors result no doubt from the instructions in the procedure in the link above to modify `build.xml`, which is a file created by `Ant` for the project.

The procedure adds `<target>` to `build.xml`, specifically including ALL of these lines:

```
  <target name="package-for-store" depends="jar">

        <!-- Change the value of this property to be the name of your JAR,
             minus the .jar extension. It should not have spaces.
             <property name="store.jar.name" value="MyJarName"/>
        -->

        <property name="store.jar.name" value="SCHEDULAR"/>

        <!-- don't edit below this line -->

        <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
        <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

        <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

        <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>

        <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
            <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>

        <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
            <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
            excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
        </zip>

        <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>

    </target>
```

Specifically, the relevant line for me is:

```
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="Searchy"/>
```

(where `Searchy` is the user-supplied name for the "fat" .jar file).

Here is the error:

```
ant -f "C:\\Users\\Dov\\Google Drive\\NetBeansProjects\\SearchyTableSwing" -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\SearchyTableSwing\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\SearchyTableSwing\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\SearchyTableSwing\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\SearchyTableSwing\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\SearchyTableSwing\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\SearchyTableSwing\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\SearchyTableSwing\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 11 source files to C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\SearchyTableSwing\build\classes
compile:
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\SearchyTableSwing\build
Copy libraries to C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\SearchyTableSwing\dist\lib.
C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\SearchyTableSwing\nbproject\build-impl.xml:981: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\SearchyTableSwing\nbproject\build-impl.xml:825: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ResourceUtils.copyResource(ResourceUtils.java:439)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:559)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:519)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:480)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:443)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:409)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:384)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:322)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.copylibstask.CopyLibs.execute(CopyLibs.java:206)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor284.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor284.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor284.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

No line of my code was flagged; if I simply RUN the project (F6), it's fine.

I have tika-app-1.9.jar as a Library, and it's huge, but in a prior version of this program, I was able to clean and build, including making a "fat" .jar file, with no problem.

Any thoughts about the cause and what to do about it?

*** EDIT ***

Part of the procedure is to right click `build.xml` (Files pane) and click `Run targets` | `Other targets` | `package-for-store`, which begins clean and build process.

Upon getting the error if I immediately repeat requesting `package-for-store`, a different error arises: `Unable to delete file C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\SearchyTableSwing\store\Searchy.jar`. If I try to delete it myself, I have to do so as administrator; even then I can't.

So I removed the lines added to `build.xml` and did a normal clean and build, which removed `Searchy.jar` from the `store` folder, which I then deleted.

I put the lines back into `build.xml` and requested `package-for-store` and got a fat jar file. No errors. Executes properly.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very bad workaround is, before requesting `package-for-store`, delete the `store` folder. So far it works.

**EDIT**

Not any more.

Surely there's either a bug that needs reporting or a better solution.

***EDIT***

Ah, yes. There IS a bug right [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57533) along with comments:

`Guess it would be worth fixing in the next release :->`

`... and a good NPE-checker of the IDE should have detected this, too :->`

`2015-02-04 10:15:06 UTC
This is a situation that probably doesn't happen too often - source and target location of rename are on different file systems and an IOException occurs while copying.  Still it's strange it hasn't been reported before.  Thanks!`

`looking at the sourcecode (ResourceUtils.java line:439) a null-reference for "project" must be the culprit:
a)
   try {
        copyUsingFileChannels(sourceFile, destFile);
        copied = true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        project.log("Attempt to copy " + sourceFile
                    + " to " + destFile + " using NIO Channels"
                    + " failed due to '" + ex.getMessage()
                    + "'.  Falling back to streams.",
                    Project.MSG_WARN);
    }`

**But that's not what's happening here.........**

`b)`

```
It would also crash in the streamCopy-fallback at the second location with a NPE because auf procect=null
    at line 439:
        private static OutputStream getOutputStream(Resource resource, boolean append, Project project)
            throws IOException {
        if (append) {
            Appendable a = resource.as(Appendable.class);
            if (a != null) {
                return a.getAppendOutputStream();
            }
            project.log("Appendable OutputStream not available for non-appendable resource "
                    + resource + "; using plain OutputStream", Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
        }
        return resource.getOutputStream();
    }
```

**Whatever... Is it Netbeans or Ant or ........ that needs fixing?**

Comment: Ant 1.9.6 does better. [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147796/ant-1-9-4-wont-clean-and-build-netbeans-8-0-2-project-using-java-8-gives-null)